# If $\bigcup A$ is a transitive set then A is also transitive.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the following true:

If $\bigcup A$  is a transitive set then A is also transitive.

Thoughts:

1. A is a transitive set if

$x \in y \in A \implies x\in A$

2. I think the opposite is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counterexample:
$A = \{\{ \emptyset\}\}$.

Comment: Is $\bigcup A = \{ \emptyset\}$?

Comment: Yes. You can check that using definition of sum.